# Syntax error on this line of code?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, syntax

I'm a beginner trying to create a SQLite Database in an android application, trying to use:

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE " +TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+
            " (" +TableInfo.HOME_TEAM+ " TEXT, " +TableInfo.AWAY_TEAM+ " TEXT);" ;
```

No errors displaying until runtime which gives: 
SQLiteException: near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE_TABLE Team_info (Home_team_name TEXT, Away_team_name TEXT);

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `CREATE TABLE` instead of `CREATE_TABLE`? That would certainly be more conventional SQL...

Answer (score 2):

It should be CREATE TABLE. with a space, not a underscore.
And you should use a StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings. Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("CREATE TABLE ");
    sb.append(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME);
    sb.append(" (");
    sb.append(TableInfo.HOME_TEAM);
    sb.append(" TEXT, ");
    sb.append(TableInfo.AWAY_TEAM);
    sb.append(" TEXT);");

    public String CREATE_QUERY = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Modern Java compiler automatically compile string concat operations into StringBuilder operations: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Change you create table statement for:

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " +TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+
        " (" +TableInfo.HOME_TEAM+ " TEXT, " +TableInfo.AWAY_TEAM+ " TEXT);" ;
```